# HTML form layout problems

Tags: jquery, html, css, clone

I am new to jQuery and PHP so I know my coding is very crude at best but I need help with this.

My PHP coding:

```
<td style="width: 39px; height: 30px;">

<select id="choice" name="choice" class="ddl" style="width: 150px">
<?php foreach($xml->children() as $pizza){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $pizza; ?>" selected=""><?php echo $pizza; ?></option>
<?php }?>
</select></td>
        <td style="height: 30px; width: 32px;">
        <input id="num" name="num" class="dd2" style="width: 46px" 
        type="number"></td>
        <td style="height: 30px; width: 91px;">
        <input TYPE = "button" id="addbt" Name = "addbt" VALUE = "Add Pizza" class="auto-style1"></td>
        <td style="height: 30px">
        <input TYPE = "button" id="removebt" Name = "removebt" VALUE = "Remove A Pizza" class="auto-style1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 131px; height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 39px; height: 30px;">

        &nbsp;</td>
        <td style="height: 30px; width: 32px;">
        &nbsp;</td>
        <td style="height: 30px" colspan="2">
        &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 131px">


     <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Submit Order"></td>
        <td colspan="4"><input id="reset" type="button" value="Reset   Order"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<p>&nbsp;</p> &nbsp;&nbsp;
</form>
```

The jQuery coding is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $("#addbt").click(function () {
 $('#choice').clone()
     .attr('id', 'choice' + $('.ddl').length)
     .attr('name', 'choice' + $('.ddl').length)
     .insertAfter(".ddl:last");
 $('#num').clone()
     .attr('id', 'num' + $('.dd2').length)
     .attr('name', 'num' + $('.dd2').length)
     .insertAfter(".dd2:last");});

 $("#removebt").click(function () {
 $("#choice1").remove();
 $("#num1").remove();
 });    


 $('#reset').click(function() {
 location.reload();});
 </script>
```

How can I influence the layout of the clones? When I create more than five clones they no longer are equal in height.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: The clones and placed in the same 'box', since they drop down list (dd1) and the number counter (dd2) are different after 5 clones the clones are no longer aligned properly.

Comment: Ryan, would you add a screenshot, or (better still) put this on a live website (e.g. JSFiddle)? That would likely make your question clearer.

Comment: @halfer - Of course: http://jsfiddle.net/A6h24/
I never used JSFiddle but here

Comment: Much better! I take it that the problem is that, when you click on "Add Pizza", the menus are not aligned with the input boxes? It would be better to put these together in a `<div>`, but you have put the menus in one `<td>` and the input boxes in another.

Comment: So I would start off with merging the cells for the selects and input boxes (use colspan) and then add in a new `<div>` for each new row required. You can then use CSS to vertically align the elements inside each.

Comment: I tried the <div> is cloned with a new name but the menu and input lose their ids...they arent added with a +1 with every clone. I dont know. Im new to PHP and Jquery so it can be im doing the right thing wrongly...

Comment: Your menu and input don't have to have `id` attributes - if they are contained within a div, then just clone the div, and set an `id` on the new div. Ultimately, you need to design a way in which your elements have a chance of lining up reliably, and this isn't it - so switch to divs (or even a sub-table would work) and then sort your problems from there.

Comment: No worries. Just so you know, "best practice" tends to shy away from tables used to line up input forms (divs and spans with appropriate CSS will do the job now). However many a legacy system is stuffed full of the table approach (it used to be the only reliable way to line things up) and it's perfectly OK for learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different margins on your input and select elements, so adding this CSS rule fixes it:

```
#table input, #table select {
    margin: 2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A6h24/4/

Comment: This does give the elements more room to breathe, but the difference in height between the two types of input device still means that the vertical alignment increasingly breaks as more order lines are added. Perhaps a static height would fix this? (I'd argue that putting more than one line in the same `<td>` is a core problem anyway and should be abandoned, but... :).

Comment: Wow...I should have though of this... Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome! Whenever you encounter some misalignments like those, there are 95% chances you can fix it with CSS. If not, then you have a misformatted HTML. :)

@halfer Well yeah, the idea is to make those elements as tight as possible by defining their style as specifically as possible... ideally breaking away from the table design as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Enclose every dropdown/number couple into a `<TD>` tag to keep them paired. Your HTML body is not well designed, that's why you are producing this bug. Now you have a `<TD>` for selects and a `<TD>` for inputs... so you have two independent string HTML entities enclosing the different categories... and this leads to a mismatch as they are both independent.

```
<td style="width: 39px; height: 30px;">         
    <select id="choice" name="choice" class="ddl" style="width: 150px"></select>
    <input id="num" name="num" class="dd2" style="width: 46px" type="number">
</td>
```

You have to rewrite just a little bit your JS code also.

Comment: I know the coding is primitive. Im still learning. Its a project to make it 'fully' functional.

Comment: Sorry... malformed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach you can take:

```
<td colspan="2">
    <div class="pizza-order-line">
        <select ... ></select>
        <input ... />
    </div>
</td>
```

In your CSS:

```
div.pizza-order-line select {
    margin-right: 4px;
}

div.pizza-order-line input {
    ....
}
```

This way, you can be reasonably sure the browser "knows" what things need to line up. If you put several items in table cells however, unless they have a guaranteed height, they won't line up properly.

Comment: No probs. As I mentioned on Shomz's answer, a static height for the select and input items (say 2em to start experimenting with) might help vertical alignment.